# Syntax Error near unexpected token `do - when converting upper case to lower case

Tags: bash

Here is the error am getting after running the script below. I have read through the other responses for the similar error but cannot find an answer. can someone see what could be going wrong with the script below?

Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
'bash: lowerit.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'bash: lowerit.sh: line 7: `  do
```

Script:

```
for x in `ls`
  do
  if [ ! -f $x ]; then
    continue
  fi
  lc=`echo $x  | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
done
```

Comment: Due to the error messages starting with `'` instead of ending with them, this looks like a file encoding issue. Can you run `cat -v lowerit.sh` and see if each line ends with `^M`?

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this in the first place. Use `for x in *`.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the unexpected token is `do\r`.

Comment: That code runs for me.  I think I saw a first version which was different (not just the formatting, at least the `ls` was not inside backticks).  As another commenter noted, use `for x in *`, and also quote your `"$x"` expansion in both places.

Comment: @Fred If you look at the edit history, the *only* change made to the post was to indent the code to create a code block; no additional line breaks were added.

Comment: I still see `ls` without backticks in the edits view, and I copy and pasted the code I am referring to to indent it on my side (before refreshing and seeing the indented version), so there has to be something wrong with my browser then.

Comment: @chepner Ok, I understand, the backticks were showing as formatting, hence when I copy/pasted them, only the text was copied, not the backticks.

Comment: @thatotherguy - Yes, each line ends with ^M

Comment: @chepner - I made the changes "for x in * and also quoted "$x" in both the places - still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, you would. See the linked duplicate. Using `ls` was a separate problem, unrelated to your immediate error.

Comment: Thanks everyone; the issue was with the carriage returns and after using the "dos2unix" command, the script worked just fine :)

Answer (score -2):

you need `;` after `ls` in for statement or just break line before "do"

Comment: looks like "that other guy" fixed it by editing your question :)

Comment: No, he just fixed the formatting. The line break was already there.

Comment: That was my point, the script is ok now, since "\`do" was at the end of error message. Just add ; like "`;do" and it should be ok regardless if line ends between or not

Comment: The script hasn't changed. It's not OK; see the error messages above.